# Dojo version upgrade from 1.3 to 1.7.3

Tags: dojo

While changing the dojo version from **1.3 to 1.7.3**, I simply replaced all my dojo 1.3 folder files with dojo 1.7.3. After rebuilding my web application, I am getting error hxrFailed at dojo.js, line no 15.

What is the wrong that I am facing here? Do I need to change any existing code. Is there any document to refer for all the required changes.

Please help me to get out from this issue.

Thanks,
Sridhar.ch

Answer (score 1):

Lots changed and there are some lengthy tutorials to help you migrate. Check out the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) tab on Dojo's website:

1.x to 2.0 migration guide:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html

Updated buildsystem tutorial:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build

In theory the current (1.8) build system is backward compatible until 2.0, but in practice I'm not sure it is 100% backward compatible because my 1.6 build profile didn't work with 1.7.x and up. I didn't try that hard to get it to work though.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the same. the xhrFailed error occurred for me for multiple reasons. One of the reason was a missing a file in the define as below:

`define(["something/was/missing/here"],function(){});`.

Another cause for the same error occurred was when a folder in a path of a dependency was renamed but not updated in the application build profile. (This case only if your are doing custom builds).

See if that is the case!